# Convert Delphi to Borland C++ builder

Tags: delphi, animation, cursor, c++builder

How to  convert this Delphi code :

```
const
  cnCursorID1 = 1;
begin
  Screen.Cursors[ cnCursorID1 ] :=
    LoadCursorFromFile(
      'c:\winnt\cursors\piano.ani' );
  Cursor := cnCursorID1;
end;
```

to C++ Builder

Answer (score 7):

The following ought to work, although I haven't tested it.

```
const int cnCursorID1 = 1;
Screen->Cursors[cnCursorID1] = LoadCursorFromFile("c:\\winnt\\cursors\\piano.ani");
Cursor = cnCursorID1;
```

(If you're a regular C++Builder user, you'll find that a lot of example code and third-party libraries are in Delphi, so it's worth learning at least enough Delphi to read it and translate it yourself.)

Comment: +1 for excellent advice. I - luckly - started with Delphi (1996 yikes!), **INCREDIBLY** and **HUGELY** superior to everyother other offering for developing on Windows at the time. The switch to C++ Builder 4 years later was a sinch). Microsoft had nothing to compete with Delphi & C++ Builder **imho** until .Net C# arrived on the scene (I had spent years broken and bleeding on the VB cross before finding Delphi).

Answer (score 2):

Caveat: Code compiled by eye, don't have Borland compiler to hand.

```
{
    const int cnCursorID1 = 1;
    Screen->Cursors[ cnCursorID1 ] =
        LoadCursorFromFile("c:\\winnt\\cursors\\piano.ani" );
    Cursor = cnCursorID1;
}
```

Comment: Apologies, just changed `Screen.Cursors` to `Screen->Cursors`